# mincer-zarnowitz regressions

Tags: least-squares

I run a regression of $y$ on lagged $x$ and a constant from time t till time T:

$y_t=\alpha+\beta x_{t-1}$

The $R^2$ is 1%.

I then run the same regression over rolling window, from time 1 till time $t, t+1,...,T$. I store the coefficients and compute forecasts of $y_{t},...,y_T$ as fitted values.

I then regress the actual $y$'s on forecasted $y$'s and a constant. The $R^2$ goes up to 15%.

My question is why. The forecast is based on $x$, so I don't see how it can outperform $x$ itself.

The only reason I can find is that the forecasted $y$ is based on a rolling window, implying that it is based on the most recent ("relevant" x's), while in the frist regression we equally weight all x's...